# If $X_j$ is iid Unif$(-1,1)$ and $Y_n=\frac{\sum X_j}{\sum X_j^2+\sum X_j^3}$, show that $\sqrt{n}Y_n\rightarrow N(0,3)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $X_j$ is iid Unif$(-1,1)$ and $\displaystyle Y_n=\frac{\sum X_j}{\sum X_j^2+\sum X_j^3}$, show that $\sqrt{n}Y_n\rightarrow N(0,3)$ in distribution.

I know from central limit theorem that $\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{n}\sum X_j \rightarrow N(0,\frac{1}{3})$ but I'm not sure how to show the denominator of $Y_n$ goes to some constant in probability or something else in distribution.

Comment: You should assume some independence otherwise it is obviously false.

Comment: Yes the $X_j$'s are independent and identically distributed

Comment: Do you know the [Slutsky lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, so I show the denominator goes to a constant using weak law of large numbers?

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, it is the denominator of $$
\sqrt{n}\cdot Y_n  = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum X_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^3}
$$

Comment: thank you! i was trying to hammer it into the second order delta method, without thinking of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I convert my comments into an answer.

First remark that: $$
\sqrt{n}\cdot Y_n  = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum X_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^3}.
$$

The numerator converges in law to a normal random variable by the Central Limit Theorem.

The denominator converges almost surely (in probability is sufficient) to some constant by the Law of Large Numbers.

Determine the variance of the normal random variable, the limit constant for the denominator, and finally conclude with Slutsky's lemma.

Comment: I find that I get $\sqrt{n}Y_n\rightarrow N(0,1)$ instead of $N(0,3)$ as the question wants, since $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2$ goes to $1/3$ in prob and $\frac{1}{3}\sum X_i^3$ goes to 0 in prob, and the numerator is $\sqrt{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ goes to $N(0,1/3)$ in dist. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @lightfish: your mistake is that the second parameter of the normal distribution is the *variance*, so if $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1/3)$, then $3\times Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,3^2\times 1/3) = \mathcal{N}(0,3)$.